# Overlap of text and grouped image in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, images, layout, margins

I am using Microsoft Word 2013 on Windows 7 x64 and I am having issues with overlapping text with grouped text and images. When I do the following:

1. insert an image (less than half of the page)
2. make the layout to be 'Top and Bottom'
3. insert a caption for image
4. group the image and its caption (totally, about half of the page)
5. insert another similar page like before and group it by its caption
6. group two grouped previous images to create, finally, one image, as large as a total page
7. set the layout of the big image as 'Top and Bottom'

It seems to be well but when I drag it and drop on the previous page one line of my texts comes 
below the image (image is as large as the page, so the line comes in the margin!)

I tested both 'move with text' and 'fix position on page' but no difference; the stubborn line 
stays in the margin!

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the layout to Square and then you can drag and drop.